# Windows 7's RAM memory management/paging files

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have an AMD64 machine with 4GB of RAM that has recently had Windows 7 installed on it.

The hard drive is now being accessed 1/sec--rhythmically. It appears to me that it is paging constantly.

However memory diagnostics indicate only 20% of the RAM is being utilized.

I know how to change the size of the paging file, but without disabling it all together how can you set it to address more ram and do less paging?

Comment: if win 7 was recently installed its possible the frequent HDD access you are witnessing is just the indexer for the desktop search, especially if you have a good amount of pre-existing files carried over

Comment: It's probably not paging activity you're seeing.  Aside from the hard drive being busy every 1 second, what leads you to think it's a memory/paging issue?  Does it only do this when idle?  Does it do it in safe mode?

Comment: How did you determine it is accessing the page file? Win 7 is always accessing the hard drive compared to XP, and its not the page file.

Answer (score 1):

Hard page faults are an indication of paging, not regular disk activity.

Open up Resource Monitor to see what processes are accessing the disk.